# How to resubmit app by removing all the permission once this is rejected by google play

Tags: android, google-play

I had published one app "GDC" and this is published properly but from last few days this is removed from play store due to permission not described properly. Now I have removed all the permissions from my app but at the time of submitting update google play console is asking "to check at least on checkbox related to permission and core functionality". Please help me to know what I need to do for submitting my new update.

[Please find the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u9kO.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. See meta

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your app and fill the form stating that you don't need any permission. This can be done using the checkboxes for providing appropriate response. Also there is a text box where you can give your explanation in 500 characters that why your app should not be blocked by google.

Similar thing happened with my app 5-6 days ago and i did the same thing.

PS:- remove any alpha or beta apk too, else google will again block your apk.

Comment: In my case I have removed all the permissions from my app but this is still asking for checking at least one checkbox, and showing one permission which I have used in old version apk.